# CSS Selector Syntax for nested bracket expressions

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select the following (which is created by jquery validate)?

```
<label class="error" for="location[]">...</label>
```

The CSS Selector

```
.error[for=location[]]
```

does not work neither

```
.error[for=location]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put attribute value in quotes in selector

```
.error[for="location[]"]
{
    color:red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ2nN/

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the attribute value by quotes `"` as:

```css
.error[for="location[]"]
```

Or use a leading back-slash `\` to **[escape](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)** the brackets as:

```css
.error[for=location\[\]]
```

However, you can also use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as `for^=location`.